# Is my solution to this problem inefficient? (freecodecamp)

Tags: javascript

The code seems to give the results I'm looking for, though the answer isn't accepted by FreeCodeCamp. Obviously their code looks a bit nicer/is more compact, aside from that would their be any other disadvantages to doing it my way? Perhaps performance wise?

**The Brief/Goal**

You are given two arrays and an index.

Use the array methods slice and splice to copy each element of the first array into the second array, in order.

Begin inserting elements at index n of the second array.

Return the resulting array. The input arrays should remain the same after the function runs.

**My Code**

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
 let arr3 = arr2.slice(0, n);
 let arr4 = arr2.slice(n);
 arr3.push(arr1);
 arr3.push(arr4);
 return arr3;
}
```

**Their solution**

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  let localArray = arr2.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  localArray.splice(n, 0, arr1[i]);
  n++;
}
  return localArray;
```

}

Comment: The two functions you provided are totally different. Calling `frankenSplice([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], 2))`, **your code** yields `[5, 6, [1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8]]`, whereas **their code** yields `[5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]`. So your solution is not correct to begin with.

Comment: Ah alright, might be an issue with their interface then, when I console log your example it doesn't show any of the brackets so it looked like it was correct to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isn't accepted as you are creating an array of arrays. The two functions do different things. If you want to concatenate arrays you should use `Array.prototype.concat` instead of the `.push` method:

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  let arr3 = arr2.slice(0, n);
  let arr4 = arr2.slice(n);
  return arr3.concat(arr1, arr4);
}
```

But your function still doesn't use the `Array.prototype.splice` method. One option is:

```
function frankenSplice(arr1, arr2, n) {
  let ret = arr2.slice();
  ret.splice(n, 0, ...arr1);
  // or: [].splice.apply(ret, [n, 0].concat(arr1));
  return ret;
}
```

A compact version of the above function:

```
function frankenSplice(a, b, n) {
  [].splice.apply(b = b.slice(), [n, 0, ...a]);
  return b;
}
```

Comment: but the question states `Use the array methods slice and splice` so slice/concat doesn't cut it :p